# How can I show the user random subwebpage when he enters my main page (index.php)?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a domain registered, e.g. mydomain.com . I would like to put there some php page (or whatever - html with jquery?, etc?) that would have a small script - when user enters this page, he will be immediately randomly redirected to one of my subpages (that are also on the same level as index.php, for example first.php, second.php, third.php) - is that achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a javascript solution:

```
  var webpages = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
  //you can have an array of the urls

  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * webpages.length - 1);
  //then generate a valid random index

  window.location.href = webpages[randomIndex];
  //redirect to a subpage randomly
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I see that someone suggested below the solution in PHP, do you know which one of those 2 is better?

Comment: @randomuser1 I have no background in PHP, it is really your choice, which one do you think is more clear and simple to implement from your perspective? To me, Javascript solution looks simpler.

Comment: Actually it does, thanks, as soon as I test the solution (tomorrow), I'll mark this answer as final, regards!

Comment: BTW. why do we need the part `+0` in randomIndex?

Comment: the javascript approach is likely better from an seo standpoint, but that's just a guess.  The problem with it in my opinion is maintenance.  If you add another page, you need to go back and add that page to your javascript array so that it can be randomly selected.  A server-side solution can scan the directory and automatically find new files...but there is also a performance concern there.  Do you want to scan a folder with 10,000 files on every page load?  Then again would you want to deliver a 10,000 item array in javascript?  I think different use cases could determine a "better" answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would scan a directory using php, pick a random file in the directory, and redirect to it.  You'd need to make sure everything in the folder was ok to redirect to.

```
$dir    = '/subpages';
$pages = scandir($dir);
$randomPage=$pages[rand(0,sizeof($pages)];
header('Location: http://example.com/'.$randomPage);
```